# Parse XML in Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, xml-parsing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

how do I parse the following xml data in XamarinForms:

```
<string xmlns="url">
{"UserName":"user1","Password":"pswd","Address1":"address"}
</string>
```

I am able to pasrse JSON data using JSON.Net component. But this particular response is wrapped up into XML. How shall I parse it?.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
var request = new RestRequest (String.Format ("{0}/allinfo", "198440"));
                client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response: "+response.Content);
                    pd.cancelDialog();
                    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(response.Content);
                    var json = xd.Root.Element("string");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Json Response: "+json);
});
```

I am able to see the "Response" but not "Json Response"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First read xml using `XLink` & `XDocument` and get property which represents json
2. Second parse json using `JSON.NET`

Here is a sample code:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);
String jsonResponse = xd.Root....
UserCredentials creds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserCredentials>(jsonResponse);
```

btw: it is not a good practice to return user credentials from the API response (and even store it at the backend).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I am not able to parse it. I have edited my question with RestSharp code where I am parsing my response. Can u have a look and tell wats the problem.

Comment: okay, I have got it i shud inckude this in the above code string json = xd.Root.Value;