# Getting image from an online XML file or a URL in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am unable to get image from a URL that is an XML response. i used following code to fetch information from this URL including image too since i thought that i will get image although the xml response has image url but i am getting image URL instead of image.
Why is it so? kindly guide me! i am a newbie to xamarin forms.

URl : https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&title=Dune

CODE:

```
 XElement search_result =(from xFi in Xdoc.Descendants("book")
             where (xFi.Element("country_code").Value == "PK") || (xFi.Element("language_code").Value == "eng")
             select xFi).FirstOrDefault();
        if (search_result != null)
        {   search.Text=
                   "Title: " + search_result.Element("title").Value + "\n" +
"Average Ratings:  " + search_result.Element("average_rating").Value + "\n" +
"ISBN: " + search_result.Element("isbn").Value + "\n" +
  "PUBLICATION YEAR: " + search_result.Element("publication_year").Value + 
  "\n" +"PUBLISHER: " + search_result.Element("publisher").Value + "\n" +
   "DESCRIPTION: " + "\n" + search_result.Element("description").Value + "\n" 
  + "IMAGE:   " + "\n" + search_result.Element("image_url").Value + "\n";
    }    else
        {
            search.Text = "Found Nothing";
        }
```

Comment: there is nothing in your code to load an image from the url

Comment: You should first parse the xml to get the image url and then load image through the url.

Comment: could you guide me about parsing by giving some resources?

Comment: Do research and you will find useful threads like: [Parse XML in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264588/parse-xml-in-xamarin-forms) and [Xml parse and binding to listview on xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390579/xml-parse-and-binding-to-listview-on-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

assuming I have an `Image` control on my page named "bookimage"

```
var url = search_result.Element("image_url").Value;
bookimage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(url));
```

this is clearly explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#download-images)

Comment: i will try this. i hope this works! But please could you elaborate what is an image control? as i m a newbie. Thanks Jason!